# jQuery object .value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am building a simple chat and am stuck on front-end.

I want to ask a user for his name and desired room before loading the chat window and I need that data in some variables. The problem is that the browser only logs `undefined`. I tried logging directly from the code and from Chrome console, too.

```
var nameChoice, roomChoice;

var init = function() {

    $("#init-name").removeClass("hidden").animate({"left" : "35%"}, 300); //slide in name form

    $("#init-name .btn-form").click(function() {

        nameChoice = $("#init-name input").value; //save chosen name in nameChoice?
        console.log(nameChoice); //debug
        $("#init-name").animate(
            {"left" : "-35%"}, 300,
            function() {
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
                $("#init-room").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#init-room").animate({"left" : "35%"}, 300);
        });  //remove name form and slide in room form in callback
    });
    $("#init-room .btn-form").click(function() {
        roomChoice = $("#init-room select").value; //save chosen room in roomChoice?
        console.log(roomChoice); //debug
        $("#init-room").animate(
            {"left" : "-35%"}, 300,
            function() {
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
                $("#chat-main").removeClass("hidden");
        }); //remove room form and show page in callback
    });
}
$(document).ready(init);
```

Does it have to do anything with variable scope (I did put them out of any function)?

Comment: Can you provide the html code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Change to $("#init-name").val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
nameChoice = $("#init-name input").value; //save chosen name in nameChoice?*
```

to this

```
nameChoice = $("#init-name input").val(); //save chosen name in nameChoice?*
```

and also this

```
roomChoice = $("#init-room select").value; //save chosen room in roomChoice?
```

to this

```
roomChoice = $("#init-room select").val(); //save chosen room in roomChoice?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `val` function in order to get the value.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
// Get the value from a dropdown select
$( "select.foo option:selected").val();

// Get the value from a dropdown select even easier
$( "select.foo" ).val();

// Get the value from a checked checkbox
$( "input:checkbox:checked" ).val();

// Get the value from a set of radio buttons
$( "input:radio[name=bar]:checked" ).val();
```